# MVC - base solution Vs Branched source control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, design-patterns, version-control

I'm planning an MVC application of which there will be two variants; one for the US and one for Europe. I can't foresee a 3rd (or nth) deployment ever happening.

The two applications will both share almost identical functionality but with some (reasonably) small variations in the Model, View and Controller.

We'll be using Entity Framework with a database-first approach.

The two options I see are:

1. Use a base MVC solution, alongside a solution for the specifics of each deployment - extended base Models, Controller event handlers, some carefully considered partial views and bundled CSS & JS.
2. Use a single solution for the whole project but use two version control (SVN) branches for the separate deployments

Which of these is the 'proper' approach for this type of project? Or is there a third option?

**UPDATE**: One alternative solution which has been pointed out to me, would be to actually make this one single application hosted on Azure/AWS, and with some conditional logic depending on whether the request is made from the US or EU host-header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2 will make it harder to apply enhancement. You must apply it in 2 places. It will be worse if either branch is incompatible so some adjustment / modification is needed. It will be useful if the differences between environment is big.

Option 1 is better. Please note that you will need good plan to design partial CSS / javascript code. However, with this design you will face with code duplication (which is also happen in option 2). Consider this code:

```
public void DoSomething(){
    // retrieve data
    // specific code for EU / NA
    // save data
}
```

This can lead to duplication in `retrieve data` and `save data`.

There is some trick to handle this but I think the cleanest way is to use `Dependency Injection`. With DI and decent DI Container (I'm inexperienced in configuring DI Container, so I cannot give you some suggestion which one is good), you will have benefit:

- Can handle duplicated code such as example above
- Can define some profiles for easier configuration and wiring, making the maintenance easier
- Testable